# Error: ERR_PNPM_LOCKFILE_MISSING_DEPENDENCY - Broken lockfile in pnpm installation

Tags: next.js, prisma, dependency-management, next-auth, pnpm

Title: Error: ERR_PNPM_LOCKFILE_MISSING_DEPENDENCY - Broken lockfile in pnpm installation

I am encountering an error while trying to run the pnpm install command in my project. The specific error message I'm getting is "ERR_PNPM_LOCKFILE_MISSING_DEPENDENCY - Broken lockfile: no entry for '/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/1.0.6(@prisma/client@4.14.1)(next-auth@4.22.1)' in pnpm-lock.yaml".

I have followed the suggested solution of running pnpm install --no-frozen-lockfile, but the error persists. Additionally, I have cleared the cache using pnpm cache clear --force and deleted the pnpm-lock.yaml file before reinstalling the dependencies, but the issue remains unresolved.

I suspect that there might be a deeper issue with my project's configuration or dependencies that is causing this error. I have double-checked the documentation for any troubleshooting guidance, but haven't found a solution specific to this error. The error message mentions a possible merge conflict in the lockfile, but I have resolved any known conflicts and ensured the lockfile is in a valid state.

Comment: Having the same problem on a Vercel build, but can't reproduce it in local

Comment: The problem is related with pnpm latest version. More information: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/6609

Answer (score 3, accepted):

downgrading to pnpm@8.5.1 solve this issue

Comment: I uninstalled the pnpm completely and reinstall the latest version and it worked somehow.

Comment: This worked for me too